# changing url path of background Image in css file dynamically

Tags: css

I have a background image path in my .css file as  `background-image: url('../images/someImage.png')` and that works fine, but now I want to change my path of all the instances (considering bussiness requirement) and want to have a variable in the path like `background-image: url('../images/'var(--someVariable)'/someImage.png')` but css does not recognize that variable in the url path and considers its value as `someVariable` while if I use the same variable in some other place in the same file, I get the desired value of the variable, I want to know how can we achieve dynamic background image url in .css file as I have around 5000 instances of the same in my project and want to have a central solution for all the instances. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your post to make it more readable.

Comment: You can use something like SASS, this link maybe help you: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/scss-how-to-change-the-background-url-dynamically-based-on-class

Comment: You cannot do this using only css.

Comment: This is a very good example of what CSS vars can and can not do: check the PAQs:

https://medium.com/dev-channel/css-variables-no-really-76f8c91bd34e

Comment: var(--someVariable) is a php or js variable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can keep the default `someImage.png` style in `style.css`.

In the PHP code file you can add the dynamic URL. If you are using php variable:

```
$dyn_path = $someVariable;
$img_path = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/'.$dyn_path.'someImage.png';

<style>
  .class_name{
     background-image: url('<?php echo $img_path;?>')
  }
</style>
```